# Trying to load a jar and an external class

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

In my zeppelin-env.sh I am loading a JDBC MySQL connector as jar as follows

```
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dspark.jars=/usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-java/libexec/mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar"
```

In addition, I'd like to load the Databricks CSV package which is supposed to work in 2 (or more) ways:

1. `%dep z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")`
2. `export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0"`

The first is working when **no** `SPARK_HOME` is set, `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` however is only taken into account when an external Spark home **is** set.

How can I load the databricks CSV package **without** setting `SPARK_HOME`, or, how can I load all the other jars that get included when using the embedded Spark libraries, without setting `SPARK_HOME`?

I'd actually prefer to use a separate Spark installation that I can update independently of Zeppelin, however I fear incompatibilities that I don't have when sticking to the embedded Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did set SPARK_HOME using an external Spark install which seems faster and was incredibly easy to install w/ `brew install apache-spark`.

> Reading the [documentation](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/interpreter/spark.html) would have helped I guess

Simply add a `--jars` option the SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS where you specify the JAR to be loaded. Alternatively, create a `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file where you specify the files, packages and jars to be loaded.